# Error after deleting NSManagedObject "The operation couldn’t be completed"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

so I'm having a Core Data & iCloud combined Database that is working fine for me.

Some users though had a certain crash after trying to delete NSManagedObject's that are respresented in an UITableView. In the debug-logs that I attach to the crashreports there is the following error-log before the crash:

```
2013-05-08 22:38:51.851 MyApp[11819:907] Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134030 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134030.)", {
}
```

Unfortunately the info about the error: {} is empty and I never had the error myself, so I don't know how to recreate it. It did occur at least 21 times for customers though.
(Whats even worse is, once they reopen the App, some NSManagedObject is in an invalid state and my tableview has problems loading it. But that just at the side)

The actual error is "SIGABRT" in " tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:", here is the respective code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        ICLog(@"Deleting the row %i,%i from the data source", indexPath.row, indexPath.section);
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        //Save the context
        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }   
}
```

PS: From the Logs its also clear that this is all run from the main thread.

Anyone here who had this problem too?

## **UPDATE**:

Luckily I had the same error in another App I'm working on just now, in a device I have access too (so far I had never saw this happening on any of my devices), so now I can investigate it while it happens. This is what I found out:

a) it still occurs after switching off icloud in the settings
b) the error occurs everytime I try to delete or insert any NSManagedObject, even if I do it in my Appdelegate right after starting, without ever accessing the data somewhere else

So it seems like something completely stops my databse from being updated. I can catch the above the exception, then the App at least isn't crashing. But of course no changes to the database are saved.

Answer (score 0):

Errors on [context save:] often occur when you try to save an invalid state of your datamodel.

Since you have deleted an object before, i would suspect that this object was in a relation with some other object that still is present, but now has it's relation in an invalid state (nil for a relation that is non-optional)

Checking your delete rules could help, maybe some relation to the object you delete needs to be optional or you have to propagate the deletion correctly.

Comment: Good point, but unfortunately the object in question has only one relationship, which is optional.

Comment: @Bersaelor can you please check the log for [context deletedObjects] array, to verify if the record which you are trying to delete is correct or not. Along with that, also verify [context insertedObjects], just to verify whether the object which you are trying to delete is already inserted before or not.

Comment: So, insertedObjects is empty shortly before deleting, as it should be because there shouldn't be any insertedobjects which haven't been saved yet.
deletedObjects has one entry, exactly the one that is going to be deleted.
but thanks for the tipp, maybe these outputs could give some insight at some point.

Answer (score 0):

I will be making some assumptions here.

What I can see is that you delete the `CoreData object` using the object in `fetchedResultsController` but you never unset the object from whatever you use as your `ViewController` `iVar` fetch storage in `numberOfRowsInSection` and re-organise your table `index` after deletion.

Let say your original `[indexPath.row count] is 7` then you go on and delete `indexPath.row = 5` from your `tableView`. Then you go on and try to delete another object  at `indexPath.row = 6` that item exists on your tableView index because you havent re-organised the `indexs`, but it wont exist in `CoreData`.... given that now the max count is `6` that the index value is now `5` of what originally was `6`.... This could be what your users are experiencing...

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [yourFetchedDataVariable count];
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        ICLog(@"Deleting the row %i,%i from the data source", indexPath.row, indexPath.section);
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
        [context deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        //Save the context
        NSError *error;
        if (![context save:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
        // the possible solution
        [yourFetchedDataVariable removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        // also now you want to re-order your array index...
        [yourTable reloadData]; // and re order your table indexses aswell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the big answer, I see your point. But I never retain any pointer to the fetched objects (only set up labels in Cells with strings in cellForRowAtIndexPath).
I don't have to reload the Tableview because my UIViewController is the delegate of the NSFetchedResultsController, which observes changes to its objects and sends me calls in controllerWillChangeContent and controller:didChangeObject.

Comment: Did you NSLog your call backs? Try testing by deleting one element before the last one (in the tableview) and then try to delete the last one after you commited that change. maybe there is an error there?

Comment: Yes, regardless which order I try to delete everything works and I can't recreate it.
Luckily I had the same error in another App I'm working on, in a device I have access too (so far I had never saw this happening on any of my devices), so now I can investigate it while it happens.
So far I can only say it happens with iCloud turned off and it happens regardless of the amount of objects or the order in which they are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The optional relationship are you sure it is optional? and optional in what sense to Xcode? I ahd this issue once and it was due to a "optional" relationship.